# How do I exchange a code for a long lived token via the Facebook API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, reactjs, facebook-graph-api

My app is a react front-end with rails back-end. We are using Alt JS for flux. I am following the instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension) to get a long lived access token from Facebook for each client using the app. Everything worked fine until the last step - swaping the code retrieved by the back end for a client-specific long lived access token. I am making the request here:

```
getLongLivedToken: {
  remote(store) {
    return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=${store.fbTokenCode}&client_id=${store.clientId}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000`
    })
    .then(function(response){
      return response
    })
  },
  success: FacebookActions.receivedLongLivedToken,
  error: FacebookActions.longLivedTokenFailed
}
```

When the API call is attempted I get `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?code=xxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

I tried navigating to the url just in my browser and it did return the token. It just won't work through the app. Other calls to the same api work just fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you whitelist your domain (localhost:3000) in the facebook app settings?

Comment: @31piy I tried and it said top-level domains are not allowed